# Как указать скидку возле цены в WooCommerce - страница одного продукта

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Я пытаюсь добавить скидку рядом с ценой на странице одного продукта (см. изображение)

[image: (см. Изображение)]

Я использую следующий код, но, к сожалению, результата не совсем ожидаемый.

```html
<?php
// Добавляем значение сэкономленных процентов рядом с ценой у товаров
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_price_html', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $product ) {
$percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
return $price . sprintf( __(' Экономия %s', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' );
}
?>
```

Comment: И Что не так то?

Comment: данный код у меня не работает с вариативными товарами